# generate thumbnail for every image in folder

Tags: bash, shell, image-processing, imagemagick, thumbnails

I am trying to write a bash script that generates small thumbnail versions for every image in a folder, so I can use it for more efficient image loading in react.

The selected answer from this question I have been trying to get working;
[Bash script to create customized thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12913667/bash-script-to-create-customized-thumbnails)

By using this modified code:

```
#!/bin/bash
THUMBS_FOLDER=./aesthetic-images/thumbnails
for file in ./aesthetic-images/*
do
  # next line checks the mime-type of the file
  IMAGE_TYPE=`file --mime-type -b "$file" | awk -F'/' '{print $1}'`
  if [ x$IMAGE_TYPE = "ximage" ]; then
      IMAGE_SIZE=`file -b $file | sed 's/ //g' | sed 's/,/ /g' | awk  '{print $2}'`
      WIDTH=`echo $IMAGE_SIZE | sed 's/x/ /g' | awk '{print $1}'`
      HEIGHT=`echo $IMAGE_SIZE | sed 's/x/ /g' | awk '{print $2}'`           
      # If the image width is greater that 200 or the height is greater that 150 a thumb is created
     if [ $WIDTH -ge  201 ] || [ $HEIGHT -ge 151 ]; then
        #This line convert the image in a 200 x 150 thumb 
        filename=$(basename "$file")
        extension="${filename##*.}"
        filename="${filename%.*}"
        convert -sample 200x150 "$file" "${THUMBS_FOLDER}/${filename}_thumb.${extension}"   
     fi
  fi     
done
```

While my project layout looks like so, calling the bash .sh script inside the /src/ folder:

[image]

But running the script with `bash generate-thumbnails.sh` leads to errors in console:

```
$ ./generate-thumbnails.sh
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: progressive: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 17: convert: command not found
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 12: [: -ge: unary operator expected
```

Is it a problem with how I configured the bash script? Or my process in calling it?

Comment: I have a concern about the error massage saying `convert: command not found`. Is `convert` command or `ImageMagick` installed in your system?

Comment: What is output if you type `convert --version` on command line?

Comment: just tested, i didnt have ImageMagick installed previously so i installed it, and running `convert --version` provides output: `Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23`. but running the script results in same errors: `./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 13: [: JFIFstandard1.01: integer expression expected
./generate-thumbnails.sh: line 13: [: -ge: unary operator expected`

Comment: Thank you for the testing and the prompt reply. I've posted an answer assuming `identify` command has been installed along with `convert` command. Would you please try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The usage of `file` command to determine image size is unreliable.
  The output format varies depending on the image format.
  Instead make use of `identify`, a ImageMagick suite command.
- It is not recommended to use uppercases for user variables. It may
  conflict with system variables.

Would you please try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

thumbs_folder=./aesthetic-images/thumbnails
mkdir -p "$thumbs_folder"

for file in ./aesthetic-images/*; do
    # next line checks the mime-type of the file
    image_type=$(file --mime-type -b "$file")
    if [[ $image_type = image/* ]]; then
        image_size=$(identify -format "%[fx:w]x%[fx:h]" "$file")
        IFS=x read -r width height <<< "$image_size"
        # If the image width is greater that 200 or the height is greater that 150 a thumb is created
        if (( width > 200 || height > 150 )); then
            #This line convert the image in a 200 x 150 thumb 
            filename=$(basename "$file")
            extension="${filename##*.}"
            filename="${filename%.*}"
            convert -sample 200x150 "$file" "${thumbs_folder}/${filename}_thumb.${extension}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: there seems to be some syntax error with the for loop: ```./genthumbs.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/genthumbs.sh: line 4: `for file in ./aesthetic-images/*; do```

Comment: had to format file, found solution using `vim` mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27176781/bash-file-returns-unexpected-token-do-r

testing now

Comment: Good! I was just mentioning about the line endings in DOS mode. Looking forward to the results.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a pretty solid re-implementation of your script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Checks required ImageMagic commands are available or exit fail
if ! for cmd in identify convert; do
  if ! command -V "$cmd" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    printf 'Missing ImageMagic required command: %s\n' "$cmd"
    false
  fi
done >&2; then
  exit 1
fi

img_folder=~/Images
thumbs_folder="$img_folder/thumbnails"

thumb_width=200
thumb_height=150

# Creates thumbnails directory if not exist
mkdir -p "$thumbs_folder"

for file in "$img_folder/"*; do
  # If $file = pattern then no match, exit
  [ "$file" = "$img_folder/*" ] && exit

  # Gets file MIME type or skip file if it fails
  mime_type="$(file -b --mime-type "$file" 2>&1)" || continue

  # Checks what to do based on mime-type
  case $mime_type in
    image/x-xcf) continue ;; # Not supported
    image/*) ;;              # Accept for processing
    *) continue ;;           # Not an image
  esac

  identify -format '%w %h' "$file" | {
    # Reads piped-in width and height
    read -r width height

    if [ "$width" ] && [ "$height" ] && {
      [ "$width" -gt "$thumb_width" ] || [ "$height" -gt "$thumb_height" ]
    }; then
      basename="${file##*/}"
      extension="${basename##*.}"
      ext_less="${basename%.*}"
      thumb_file="${thumbs_folder}/${ext_less}_thumb.${extension}"
      printf 'Create thumb file for %s, size: %dx%d\n' \
        "$file" "$width" "$height"
      convert -sample "${thumb_width}x${thumb_height}" "$file" "$thumb_file"
    fi
  }
done
```